# Can we use sqltap on appengine environment?

Tags: google-app-engine

### Can we use sqltap on appengine environment?

1) profiler = sqltap.start()
 2) query 
 3)statistics = profiler.collect() 
 4)print "statistics",

---

,but I am not getting any output from .collect() method .
statistics =[] is returned

---

### appengine console output:

statistics []

statistics []

ERROR    2015-12-18 09:00:11,105 app.py:1423] Exception on /api/projects [GET]

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "./library\flask\app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app

```
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
```

File "./library\flask\app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request

```
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
```

File "./library\flask\app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception

```
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
```

File "./library\flask\app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request

```
rv = self.dispatch_request()
```

File "./library\flask\app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request

```
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
```

File "C:\Users\HP\Documents\vector\Server\src\controller\projects.py", line 237, in get_relevant

```
sqltap.report(statistics,  "report.html")
```

File "./library\sqltap\sqltap.py", line 307, in report

```
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
```

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\python\stubs.py", line 247, in **init**

```
raise IOError(errno.EROFS, 'Read-only file system', filename)
```

IOError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'report.html'

ERROR    2015-12-18 09:00:11,128 app.py:1423] Exception on /api/projects [GET]

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "./library\flask\app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app

```
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
```

File "./library\flask\app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request

```
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
```

File "./library\flask\app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception

```
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
```

File "./library\flask\app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request

```
rv = self.dispatch_request()
```

File "./library\flask\app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request

```
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
```

File "C:\Users\HP\Documents\vector\Server\src\controller\projects.py", line 237, in get_relevant

```
sqltap.report(statistics,  "report.html")
```

File "./library\sqltap\sqltap.py", line 307, in report

```
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
```

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\python\stubs.py", line 247, in **init**

```
raise IOError(errno.EROFS, 'Read-only file system', filename)
```

IOError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'report.html'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your error is on the call to `sqltap.report()` in vector\Server\src\controller\projects.py:237.

On app engine the local filesystem is read-only, and `sqltap.report()` tries to write the result to the filesystem.

Try using `sqltap.render()` that returns the result in a variable.